# typeof vs naked if in JavaScript performance wise

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement, comparison, undefined

I have two expressions and I would like to know which one is better performance wise.

1 `if(typeof a !== "undefined") {}`

2 `if(a) {}`

(I am not sure how the second expression is called, so I refer to it as a **naked if** in the question title, feel free to correct me if you know the correct term for this)

I understand that the two expressions will result in being `true` under pretty much different conditions. I am not interested in this, I am only interested in performance.

Also, I understand that the performance difference may be considered as insignificant by someone. But still I am interested in it.

From my pov they both are readable well. For my case they both are applicable. Now I need to give a performance point to one of the two options. The point will decide which approach I am going to always use in the future in case both of them are appropriate.

Thank you.

Comment: There's no significant difference in performance but there's a big difference in semantics; they do significantly different things in other words. For your application that may or may not matter.

Comment: @Pointy, thank you. I updated my question.

Comment: How often does that if get executed? Once, 10 times, 1M times? Even if one of those is ten times slower than the other, does it matter?

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: And you can't (especially in JS) assert the performance  of one statement without its surrounding

Comment: @JonasWilms, do you mean that the performance of the two options depends on the code which was executed before and which will be executed after? Thank you.

Comment: @Barmar, I am sure that my desire to have my choice of the two options being explained and proved to be a good choice is not a root of evil. Thank you.

Comment: @Barmar, the very main point here is not to optimize. My intent is to make a right decision and I want to do it using the optimization. So, here the optimization is not a result, but a tool. Thank you.

Comment: That's the wrong idea. Write code in the most clear way, don't worry too much about performance. If you discover that your solution is too slow, then you optimize. The difference in this case will be negligible in 99% of applications.

Comment: @Barmar, as I mentioned in my question `From my pov they both are readable well.`. Thank you.

Comment: Then you should think about which one best represents the logic, for the benefit of other readers.

Comment: @Barmar, that is a good point. Thank you. But I am still interested in knowing the answer to my question.

Comment: Use #2, it's less verbose.